# Question regarding parameter store and Cloud formation integration

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I was trying this scenario but I am not able to figure out

I have a name and value in parameter store in SSM, now I am running the CF template from CLI using code pipeline,  and I  want the CF template take values directly from parameter store and should not prompt
on screen asking me to give the value.

I tried this but it prompt me .

AWS::SSM::Parameter::value

this is prompting when I used to upload a template in screen. how to avoid it and make the script take the value from parameter store directly

Answer (score 0):

You have **two choices** for that:

1. Provide a **default value** for the parameter.
2. Use [ParameterOverrides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CloudFormation.html#action-reference-CloudFormation-config) in your CodePiepline to provide the required value for the parameter.